# Sharepoint Online: Enabling search within a shared folder for external users

Tags: sharepoint-online, external-users, sharing

I have shared a specific folder with an external user, allowing them to edit. When creating the sharing link, I selected "Specific people" and entered their email address - the link works, they verify access using the code that's emailed to them, and can see the list of files/folders, edit and so on.

Is there any way of enabling these external users to search the folder that they've been granted access to? I can see search fields when I'm logged in as a normal user, but to external users without actual accounts, I can't seem to find where to enable this option.

Does anyone know if this is something that's possible for external users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that we cannot enable search for external users currently.

Per my test in my SharePoint online environment, then I share the folder with the external user. When the external user accesses the folder, there is no search box for the external user to search.

It is by design.